# json data repeat itself 2 times

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       $("button").click(getir);
   });

    function getir() {
         $.ajax({
               dataType: "json",
               url:"get.php",
               success: function(datacall) {
                   $.each(datacall,function(index,vals) {
                       $("span").append(index + " : " + vals + "<br />");
                   });
               }
           });
    }
```

the json data is {"sez":"soze","koz":"koze"}
but i get a result like:

```
sez : soze
koz : koze
sez : soze
koz : koze
```

i couldnt get why its repeated 2 times?

Comment: Are there two spans on the page? jQuery would append the text to each span.

Comment: what's your `<html>` and `//server code` look like?

Comment: @greg, ah you are right. there are one more span in the page.

Comment: To add to @Greg's comment, your output div should have an ID and use an ID selector, rather than selecting all span elements.

Comment: thank you Fosco, i' ve assigned an id to target span now it's working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you by chance have 2 spans on top of each other?

your function works fine: see this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/G2ntr/

so, either your data doesn't look like what you say it looks like,   or you've got more then one span in your html.

Answer (score 1):

If there is more than one span on the page, each span will have the text appended to it. Restrict jQuery to operating on only one span by specifying a more specific selector, such as an id or class.

Comment: @markusmark - I'm glad it was this simple. And welcome to Stackoverflow! If my answer (or another) answers your question then please mark it as correct by clicking the green checkmark. I hope you stick around, this is a great community.